# ICEfaces throws UnsupportedOperationException when registering OmniFaces Html5RenderKit

Tags: jsf, icefaces, omnifaces

I tried to add OmniFaces HTML5 support to a project without success.
ICEFaces throws an severity error:

```
ICEfaces rendering required by icefaces-compat.jar components. Enable via <icecore:config render="true" />.
Error Renter code hereendering View[/index.xhtml]
```

So I added icecore:config render="true" but it didn't work, throws same error.

Not sure if it's a configuration mistake.
What I've done is add to web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.HTML5_RENDER_KIT_PASSTHROUGH_ATTRIBUTES</param-name>
    <param-value>
        javax.faces.component.UIInput=x-webkit-speech,x-webkit-grammar;
        javax.faces.component.UIComponent=contenteditable,draggable
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

And in faces-config:

```
<factory>
    <render-kit-factory>org.omnifaces.renderkit.Html5RenderKitFactory</render-kit-factory>
</factory>
```

If "factory" is removed from faces-config, the project works but without HTML5 support. It seems that HTML5 render kit overrides the icefaces's kit.

One other thing that makes me think it's a config mistake is that NetBeans underlines "placeholder" attribute in an h:inputText.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't override other render kits, it just wraps the "current" render kit. It looks like that ICEfaces thinks that it's being the only JSF library in the webapp and in some way perfoming an immediate instanceof check on the render kit without inspecting the wrapped ones. Before being able to give an answer, I need to know the exact ICEfaces version so that I can look in its source code.

Comment: IceFaces version is 3.3.0. I get noticed that if you have an "ace" component, it throws that error. On the other hand, if you only use "h" or "ice" components there is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, as I suspected, ICEfaces thinks it's being the only JSF library in the webapp and is performing an immediate `instanceof` check on the `FacesContext#getResponseWriter()` without inspecting the wrapped ones. Here's an extract from [ICEfaces' `DOMContext` class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.icefaces/icefaces-compat/3.3.0/com/icesoft/faces/context/DOMContext.java#83):

```
85         ResponseWriter responseWriter = facesContext.getResponseWriter();
86         DOMResponseWriter domWriter;
87         if (responseWriter instanceof DOMResponseWriter) {
88             domWriter = (DOMResponseWriter) responseWriter;
89         } else {
90 //            domWriter = createTemporaryDOMResponseWriter(responseWriter, facesContext);
91             log.severe("ICEfaces rendering required by icefaces-compat.jar " +
92                       "components. Enable via <icecore:config render=\"true\" />.");
93             throw new UnsupportedOperationException("ICEfaces rendering required.");
94         }
```

*(note: starting at line `222` there's a similar block)*

In theory, you could workaround this by explicitly registering the ICEfaces renderkit factory **after** the OmniFaces one in `faces-config.xml`. However, I couldn't find a `RenderKitFactory` in the ICEfaces source code who's responsible for creating the `DOMRenderKit`. It appears that ICEfaces thinks it's a JSF implementation by itself and altogether overriding the default JSF implementation's `HTML_BASIC` renderkit as follows in its `/META-INF/faces-config.xml`:

```
<render-kit>
    <render-kit-id>HTML_BASIC</render-kit-id>
    <render-kit-class>org.icefaces.impl.renderkit.DOMRenderKit</render-kit-class>
</render-kit>
```

All in all, ICEfaces doesn't make it possible anymore to wrap the render kits via a factory. This is not so nice. Note that the extracted source contains an outcommented line referencing `createTemporaryDOMResponseWriter()` which does its job -almost- right. Perhaps they couldn't figure why it didn't always work and left it for what it was. Too bad.

The workaround would be to [copy the `DOMContext` class](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.icefaces/icefaces-compat/3.3.0/com/icesoft/faces/context/DOMContext.java/?v=source) into your webapp, in its original package (once deployed, classes in `/WEB-INF/classes` have precedence over the ones in `/WEB-INF/lib`, so the custom copy would be loaded instead of the ICEfaces one) and change the code starting at line `85` as follows and *remove* the entire `if-else` block thereafter:

```
85         ResponseWriter responseWriter = facesContext.getResponseWriter();
86         DOMResponseWriter domWriter = findDOMResponseWriter(responseWriter);
```

*(do the same for the block starting at line `222`)*

And add the following method:

```
private static DOMResponseWriter findDOMResponseWriter(ResponseWriter responseWriter) {
    while (!(responseWriter instanceof DOMResponseWriter) && responseWriter instanceof ResponseWriterWrapper) {
        responseWriter = ((ResponseWriterWrapper) responseWriter).getWrapped();
    }

    if (responseWriter instanceof DOMResponseWriter) {
        return (DOMResponseWriter) responseWriter;
    }
    else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("ICEfaces rendering required");
    }
}
```

That should do it for you.

Comment: Solution seems to work. Keep trying.
Muito obrigado!

Comment: @BalusC: To the `responseWrite` I have got a `com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter` object. There were only one ace:dataTable and few ice:componets inside it. Any ideas?